# Kreyszig's proof of metric space l∞ not separable

Tags: functional-analysis

In his functional Analysis book, author Kreyszig writes the following for proving l∞ not separable:

"...If we let each of these sequences be the center of a small ball, say, of radius 1/3, these balls do not intersect and we have uncountably many of them..."

**Que:** What does author mean by a ball here? I don't see the connection between sequence of 0's and 1's to a geometric ball of radius 1/3. How a sequence can be center of a geometric ball?

Comment: Can you see a sequence of three numbers being a center of a ball?

Answer (score 0):

The standard neighborhood
$$
\{x : \|x-x_0\|<r\}
$$
is called ball with center $x_0$ and radius $r$. This is a set in the metric space. Since the definition of a ball (as in golf ball) in $\mathbb R^3$ looks completely similar, people use ball to refer to such neighborhoods in all kind of metric or normed spaces.